# How to tell mypy that a class decorator adds a method to the decorated-class

Tags: python, mypy

The Python library [pure_protobuf](https://github.com/eigenein/protobuf) forces its users to use dataclasses, *and* decorate them with another decorator:

```
# to be clear: these two decorators are library code (external)
@message
@dataclass
class SearchRequest:
    query: str = field(1, default='')
    page_number: int32 = field(2, default=int32(0))
    result_per_page: int32 = field(3, default=int32(0))
```

This `@message` decorator assigns the `SearchRequest` instance a method called `dumps`:

```
SearchRequest(
    query='hello',
    page_number=int32(1),
    result_per_page=int32(10),
).dumps() == b'\x0A\x05hello\x10\x01\x18\x0A'
```

In my application code, I have a specific use-case where I need to pass an object that has the `dumps()` method. It can be a `pure_protobuf` `Message` instance like above, or it can be any other type, so long as it implements `dumps()`.

It's working fine for classes that I've defined myself and implement the `dumps()` "interface", but for `pure_protobuf` data-classes, it keeps complaining that they have no attribute `dumps()`.

What is making this more challenging is I'm not defining these `pure_protobuf` data-classes myself, these will be defined by clients of my library, so I can't simply do something (silly) like:

```
@message
@dataclass
class SearchRequest:
    query: str = field(1, default='')
    page_number: int32 = field(2, default=int32(0))
    result_per_page: int32 = field(3, default=int32(0))
    
    def dumps(self):
       self.dumps() # that is Message.dumps from the decorator
```

Am I out of options?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, you're really out of solutions here, because you need (no matter that it's external, it's not really important) `message` decorator to return `Intersection` (or `Meet` in terms of types theory) of input class and protocol with 4 methods (`dump`, `dumps`, `load`, `loads`). It is not in python type system yet and is not implemented as type checker extension. See discussion regarding `Intersection` [in this python/typing issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213).

The most interesting thing is that you *could* use pytype instead and leave `message` unannotated, according to [this tutorial](https://insanitybit.github.io/2020/07/19/intersection-types-in-python). If using another type checker is an option for you, you could declare your own `message` version:

```py
from typing import IO, Protocol, TYPE_CHECKING
from pure_protobuf.dataclasses_ import message as _message

class MessageMixin(Protocol):
    def dumps(self) -> bytes: ...
    def dump(self, io: IO) -> None: ...
    # Other definitions can go here

def message(cls):
    if TYPE_CHECKING:  # tweak
        return type(cls.__name__, (MessageMixin, cls), {})
    else:  # actually run on runtime
        return _message(cls)
```

Then users of your library can safely use this `message` implementation, because in fact it just wraps existing method for type checking purpose, not affecting runtime. So if they don't, they just have `mypy` errors (or not, if they do not use type checkers), but runtime is not affected.

However, once again, **it does not work for `mypy`**.

If you are interested in having `Intersection` in a tool like `mypy`, consider switching to [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) fork that, among other extensions, provides `Intersection` support on the best effort basis.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. I’m upvoting because of its usefulness (+ learnt something new!), but I’m looking for mypy solutions (if those exist).

Comment: The full solution here, I imagine, is to write a mypy plugin. I know Django does this to support many of its complicated idioms that don't fit into mypy natively, but I imagine it's a huge undertaking in itself.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, often the cost of retrofitting static typing into Python. At least for now and the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

mypy has a [plugin system](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#extending-mypy-using-plugins) that would allow you to inform it about the effect of your decorator. However, the plugin system is still experimental, and there is not enough information in the documentation to be able to write one. Instead, the doc recommends getting in contact with the mypy developers.