# Static type hint for decorator that adds attribute to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-typing

Is it possible to create a type hint for a class decorator that adds an attribute to the given class? Since PEP612 it's possible to use `ParamSpec` and `Concatenate` for decorators that modify signatures, but I haven't found any equivalents for decorators that modify classes.

```py
def add_x(cls_):
  cls_.x: int = 5
  return cls_

@add_x
class Example: pass
```

How would I have to type `add_x` to have `x: int` hinted on my `Example` class?

Comment: It's impossible, you'll need an `Intersection` type for that (because adding attribute is essentially mixing with `Protocol` with that attribute defined). It's not even a PEP yet, though there are discussions in progress. Please check [this issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1321) for more authoritative answer - it asks exactly about your use case.

Comment: fwiw i'm confident someone has already asked this, though I don't have time to find the original qu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell mypy that a class decorator adds a method to the decorated-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034847/how-to-tell-mypy-that-a-class-decorator-adds-a-method-to-the-decorated-class) @joel yes, here's the dupe (I answered it before, but also had some troubles finding it...)