# How do I tell PyCharm of the class variable created by a class decorator?

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy, python-decorators, python-typing

Say, I have a decorator to make logging more straightforward:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=type)


def with_logger(cls: _T) -> _T:
    from logging import getLogger

    cls.logger = getLogger(cls.__name__)
    return cls


@with_logger
class Spam:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"{Spam.logger.name = }")


Spam()
```

The code runs fine. However, both PyCharm and `mypy` complain that `Spam` has no attribute named `logger`. The line that causes the warning is `print(f"{Spam.logger.name = }")`.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034847/how-to-tell-mypy-that-a-class-decorator-adds-a-method-to-the-decorated-class), I transformed the code into the following monstrous one:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=type)


def with_logger(cls: _T) -> _T:
    from logging import getLogger
    from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

    setattr(cls, 'logger', getLogger(cls.__name__))
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        from typing import ClassVar, Protocol, cast

        class LoggerMixin(Protocol):
            from logging import Logger

            logger: ClassVar[Logger] = getLogger(cls.__name__)

        return cast(_T, type(cls.__name__, (LoggerMixin, cls), dict()))
    else:
        return cls


@with_logger
class Spam:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"{Spam.logger.name = }")


Spam()
```

Still, no avail. PyCharm, `mypy`, and `basedmypy` claim that `logger` is unresolved.

Is there anything else to do? It's been more than a year since the question.

I can explicitly type `logger` within each decorated class, but the solution is next to discarding the decorator at all:

```py
from logging import Logger, getLogger
from typing import ClassVar, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=type)


def with_logger(cls: _T) -> _T:
    setattr(cls, 'logger', getLogger(cls.__name__))
    return cls


@with_logger
class Spam:
    logger: ClassVar[Logger]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"{Spam.logger.name = }")


Spam()
```

---

As @KamilCuk suggested, a working way out is to inherit a class that creates the `logger`:

```py
from logging import Logger, getLogger
from typing import ClassVar


class BaseLogger:
    logger: ClassVar[Logger]
    
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.logger = getLogger(cls.__name__)
        return super().__new__(cls)


class Spam(BaseLogger):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"{Spam.logger.name = }")


Spam()
```

It works fine. It highlights correctly in PyCharm. I just wonder if it can be done via a decorator.

Comment: Why not inheritance?

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you. I forgot to mention that. Fixed. So, no solution via a decorator?

Comment: @KamilCuk, PyCharm accepts the solution, but `mypy` still complains.

Comment: overloading `__new__`? Just `@property def logger(self): return getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)`. It is rare that you would overload `__new__`.

Comment: This would be solvable to use decorators with intersection - currently a work in progress!

Comment: @KamilCuk, correct. But I'd make the property cached then. However, the result can't be used as a `ClassVar`. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Use `@functools.cached_property` ;)